# How to append child element to hovered element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a calendar that contains dozens of divs, and all of this divs contain a div with class name 'inner-grid`, I am using functional component, now I would like to append an HTML div only to the hovered element.

Comment: Have you look in `target`?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin updated the question check out, added the console log from target

Comment: `var imageData = document.getElementById('imageDataContaainer')` - > `imageDataContaainer` is this what you wanted the spelling to be? Looks misspelled.

Comment: @dalelandry yes that is what i wanted , and its not the problem. the problem is to append the div on hovered element

Answer (score 1):

change

```
getInnerGrid.appendChild(imageData);
```

to:

```
getInnerGrid.parentElement.appendChild(imageData);
```